# Why am I forced to decorate these classes with data contract attribute?

Tags: .net, wcf, attributes, datacontract

This is really confusing but almost for no reason my once working WCF service is forcing me to decorate two classes with the DataContract attribute even though I am not passing them back as a return value in a method or asp.net as one of the parameters to the method.

In short they do not need to be serialized. The only reason I can see is that they are objects stored as member variables within a class that has been decorated with the [DataContract] attribute? They are new objects within the object that im passing back to my WCF methods...

Anyone know why this would suddenly happen?

Comment: When you say ".. is forcing me to decorate two classes", how so?  Is it putting a gun to your head?

Comment: Please show the code and the error message.

Comment: ... if you don't decorate the properties with [DataMember], they will just turn out Null / default if you DO send them through a serialization / deserialization cycle?

Comment: it comes up with an error when I view the .svc file saying that I must decorate the db class with DataContract

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WCF supports POCO from .net 3.5

But if you want to go the POCO way then NONE of the classes directly or indirectly exposed by your service must be decorated with the DataContract attribute.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456853.aspx